# Reusing code in controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a block of code which is use in pretty much every controller, so I am wondering how, or what's the best practice for reusing code in multiple controllers

Simple example would be this

```
public String CoolCode(){
    // Stuff
    return MyStuff;
}
```

Then in another controller I just use

```
string something = CoolCode();
```

Where should I put it, and how to use it in every controller?

Comment: Whatever applies to any other class also applies to controllers - use inheritance, composition, create a helper class, an extension class, etc. It isn't possible to give a specific answer unless you specify what you want to do. Eg, a helper class can't access a controller's protected fields while a base class can. On the other hand, a base class introduces very tight coupling

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that seems like a good answer to me, you should post it as such.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would inject the helper class into the controller:

```
public interface IHelper
{
    string CoolCode();
}

public class Helper : IHelper
{
    public string CoolCode()
    {
        return "Cool code";
    }
}

public class SomeController
{
   private IHelper _helper;
   public SomeController(IHelper helper)
   {
       _helper = helper;
   }

   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       //call _helper.CoolCode();
   }
}
```

Then you would need to inject this using some sort of IoC container, I recommend [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx)

This is all quite abstract but I recommend you read up on it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560798/ASP-NET-MVC-Controller-Dependency-Injection-for-Be

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is extend the Controller class that all your controllers inherit now and use this abstraction to wrap all of your controllers that use that code:

```
public class MyControllerBase : Controller
{
   public string CoolCode() { ... } 
}
```

now you simply inherit your abstraction rather than the default one:

```
public class AnyController : MyControllerBase
{
...
}
```

However depending on what you need precisely different approaches might be more appropriate.

Comment: I would definitely favor composition over inheritance in this case.

Comment: hmm I would agree with you, though in my opinion it should vastly depend on the type of logic of that method. If its code/functionality that is specific for controller behaviour I would leave it in the abstraction, but if it is  something that is simply used in controllers but not 'cohesionally' (I just created a new word) correct than a composition would make more sense. Not sure if I explained what I mean well ... And btw because I am usually very lazy and dont want to initialize the new class in every controller I would put the composition inside the base class :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IBaseUserController
{
    string SomePropety { get; set; }

    ActionResult SignUp(string code, [Form] SomeViewModel model);
}

public class BaseUserController : Controller, IBaseUserController
{
    private static string _somePropety = "";

    public BaseUserController(){}

    public string SomePropety
    {
        get
        {
            return _somePropety;
        }
        set { _somePropety = value; }
    }

    public virtual ActionResult SignUp(string code, [Form] SomeViewModel model)
    {
        // ... CoolCode maybe use SomePropety
        return View(model);
    }
}
public class TestUserController : BaseUserController
{
    public TestUserController()
    {
        SomePropety = "Value";
    }

    public override ActionResult SignUp(string code, [Form] SomeViewModel model)
    {
        return base.SignUp(code, model);
    }

    public ActionResult SignUp2(string code, [Form] SomeViewModel model)
    {
        return base.SignUp(code, model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC controller are same as normal class and controller have the same extension .cs

So use can use static method like following.

```
HomeController objHomeController = new HomeController();
string something=  objHomeController.CoolCode();
```

Comment: Even if this can work, I completely disagree with this answer. This cause a strong coupling between two controlers. In my opininion, all "shared" code must go either in an utility/manager/whatevernameyoulike class or a base class, if the shared code applies to a base ancestor of two consuming code

Comment: I am completely agree with you Steve, My answer was just to accomplish the requirement of the Per Petter.